# R programming functions

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I'm learning R programming. I'm unable to understand how function within function works in R. Example:

```
f <- function(y) {
    function()  { y }
}

f()
f(2)()
```

I'm not able to understand why $f() is not working and showing following message:

> ```
> function()  { y }
> <environment: 0x0000000015e8d470>
> ```

but when I use $f(4)() then it is showing answer as 4.
Please explain your answer in brief so that I can understand it easily.

Comment: You're defining the inner function without calling it or storing it, so it's getting returned; you've made a function that makes functions. To make the inner function get called, wrap it in parentheses, with an extra set after: `f <- function(y) {
     (function()  { y })()
     }` though that's just equivalent to `f <- function(y){y}`

Answer (score 0):

For a more general case, let's change the "inner" function a little bit:

```
f <- function(y) {
    function(x)  { y + x}
}
```

Now `f(2)` returns a function that adds 2 to its argument. The value `2` is kept in the function's environment:

```
> f(2)
function(x)  { y + x}
<environment: 0x0000000015a690f0>

> environment(f(2))$y
[1] 2
```

.. and you can change it if you really want to but for this you need to assign a name to the output of `f()`:

```
> g <- f(2)
> environment(g)$y
[1] 2
> environment(g)$y <- 3
> g(1)
[1] 4
```

Why do you need a `g` here? Because otherwise, the environment created with `f(2)` is garbage collected immediately, so there's no way to access it:

```
> environment(f(2))$y<-4
Error in environment(f(2))$y <- 4 : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

This won't affect the case when you use, say, `f(2)` only once:

```
> f(2)(3)
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the inner function behave as the answer of the outer one son by just doing `f()`, the result is a function. The best way is to call it double `f(3)()` as the inner function doesn't take any argument.